# bash no such file

Tags: ros, setup.bash

[image: Rosanswers logo]

good afternoon
request your assistance already in my ROS installation, I get the following error
bash: / opt / ros / hydro / setup.bash: No such file or directory
after the following command: echo "source / opt / ros / hydro / setup.bash" >> ~ / bashrc.
source ~ /. bashrc, thanks for your help and your time

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/133716/bash-no-such-file/) by [felipe](https://answers.ros.org/users/11481/felipe/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-02-26

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It looks like you have a number of extra spaces in your command. It should be:

```
echo "source /opt/ros/hydro/setup.bash" >> ~ /.bashrc
source ~/.bashrc
```

Note the lack of spaces between the slashes ( / ).

You will probably have to edit your ~/.bashrc to remove the line you've added that does contain spaces; otherwise it will continue to generate errors.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-02-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2014-02-26**:
Following up please use copy and paste as much as possible when asking questions to avoid typos.